# String with 'hidden' characters cannot convert to float

Tags: string, python-2.7, character

Reading csv file, encountering strings with 'hidden' characters so to speak, evidenced by longer length of string than appears when you print the string.  Ultimately I need to convert the string into a float.  How to handle this?  Running Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)

Code:

```
    f=open('Archive_2016-02-23.csv','r')
    for line in f:
        if 'Instrument' in line: #test if header line
            continue #skip header line
    for f,b in zip(l_headers, line.split(',')):
        globals()[f]=b   #makes each header name into a variable with values
    print WPrcAvg, len(WPrcAvg), type(WPrcAvg)
    for i in WPrcAvg:
        print 'i: ', i
    WPrcAvg=WPrcAvg.replace(' ','')
    for i in WPrcAvg:
        print 'i: ', i
    print WPrcAvg, float(WPrcAvg)  #here is where error breaks the code
```

Result:

```
2.707 11 <type 'str'>
i:  
i:  2
i:  
i:  .
i:  
i:  7
i:  
i:  0
i:  
i:  7
i:  
i:  
i:  2
i:  
i:  .
i:  
i:  7
i:  
i:  0
i:  
i:  7
i:  
2.707
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readtest.py", line 35, in <module>
    print WPrcAvg, float(WPrcAvg)  #here is where error breaks the code
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague suggested this code and it worked for me.  Not that I understand the "how" and "why" of it, but this works...

```
with open('Archive_2016-02-23.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader( (line.replace('\0','') for line in f) )
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        for f,b in zip(l_headers, row):
            globals()[f]=b   #makes each header name into a variable with values
```